# (STM32F10x, IAR EW ) Self Upgrade bootloader through RS232, how to execute program in RAM after copy from FLASH

Tags: upgrade, ram, stm32, bootloader, flash-memory

I am working in STM32F103RBT6, I want to upgrade my bootloader program which i put in 0x08000000~0x08003fff, i use all other flash memory for Application code. Through the RS232, I want to upgrade the bootloader.  So i am thinking to copy the code to RAM--> execute the original bootloader in RAM --> Download the New bootloader. 
What i did is:

```
startAddr == 0x20000000
NVIC_SetVectorTable(NVIC_VectTab_RAM, 0x0); 

JumpAddress = *(__IO UINT32*)(startAddr + 4 ); 
Jump_To_Application =  (pFunction)JumpAddress;   
__set_MSP(*(__IO UINT32*) startAddr);
Jump_To_Application();
```

It doesn't work.

The question is :

1. Can i just copy the code to 0x20000000~. Should i divide the RAM into Two parts but how?
2. How can i set my Vector table location, and where can i set it? how can i deal with the "VECT_TAB_OFFSET".

It will be extremely grateful if you can give me some solution or any commands. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling code in a conventional setting (flash + RAM), code goes in a section of memory while RAM goes in another, so there's no risk of one stepping in the other's toes. Now when you copy your code to RAM, it may be that it tries to access some variables in RAM that end up being overwritten by the code you wrote, which gives rise to problems.

What you want to do is, as you say, divide the RAM in two parts. A part of it should be reserved for the code you're going to copy, and the other part for global variables and the stack. This is done through a linker script (just Google for linker script), although some IDEs may expose a preference somewhere. See, e.g., the figure in this [Coocox forum thread](http://www.coocox.org/forum/topic.php?id=3543) for Coocox, if by chance that's what you're using. What you would do in this particular case is change the start of IRAM1 to a later position, say 0x20000400, and of course adjust the size of the RAM region accordingly -- 0x00000C00 in the example. For a gcc linker script you should have something like this somewhere in the script:

```
MEMORY
{
    rom (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x00040000
    ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x0000c000
}
```

Just make a similar change to the line that starts with `ram`.

Of course, these are just example values. You need to figure out how big your code is and make sure a RAM section of at least that size is off-limits for everything else.

**Also, you need to compile your code using some sort of PIC (position independent code) option, so there's no problem with relocating the code. This is extremely important.**

You also need to relocate your vector table, as you pointed out. This is done through the System Control Block of the Cortex-M3 core, and specifically the vector table offset register, at address 0xE000ED08, which can also be accessed by the struct field SCB->VTOR if you're using the Standard Peripheral Library. There's also the `NVIC_SetVectorTable()` function from the Standard Peripheral Library. The only restriction is that the vector table must be in an address that's multiple of 512, i.e. bits 8-0 need to be 0.

By doing that, the MCU core will look for the interrupt table in the position you set. The second problem is making sure that the addresses on the vector table point to positions in RAM rather than their original positions in flash. You could fix the entries by doing some pointer arithmetic, i.e. get the pointer to a function in its original address in flash, subtract the starting flash address found in your linker script (usually 0x08000000) and then add the address where your copied code will start (say 0x20000000 if you put aside the initial region of RAM for your code as I did above). I can't think of a simpler way to do that, not that this one is particularly complicated.

Or you can bypass the whole problem and simply don't use interrupts for anything in your bootloader. When I wrote a bootloader, that's a design decision that I made, with the rationale that interrupts make code less predictable and harder to analyze. A bootloader is a piece of very critical code (hit a bug and you may brick your hardware requiring a potentially expensive fix), and at the same time, bootloaders usually don't have any hard real-time requirements or things of the sort, so you may get away with avoiding interrupts altogether while meeting design requirements. I would urge you to consider the possibility.